# How to merge multiple single-page TIFFs into a PDF with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, merge, tiff

I have a massive number of TIFF images which are single scanned pages. They are each a page of multi-page documents.

I need to be able to deliver this multi-page document to my users as a PDF. Nothing special is required except combining the images into one document, in the right order.

The images locations are provided via the result of a MySQL query in PHP as an array, i.e:

```
c:\images\04\DUDDSDFF.tif,c:\images\04\EDFRTOFN.tif,c:\images\04\EFSDOSDG.tif
```

The current dev environment I am working in uses XAMPP running on Win Server 2K3.

Any suggestions/solutions would be most appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done done something similar before where I used the [Imagick()](http://uk.php.net/Imagick) class to convert form TIFF to PNG and then used [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) to generate the PDF.

Comment: I had my head stuck with the tiff to pdf solution. It never dawned on me to do a further conversion. That's absolutely perfect thanks, I've got that working in a very basic fashion now so should be no problem converting to an on-the-fly process. Perfect answer, thank you Paul!

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdfThumb = new \Imagick();
foreach ($tiffPics as $tiffPic) {
    $pdfThumb->addImage($new \Imagick($tiffPic));
}
$pdfThumb->writeImages($absolutePdfName, true);
```

Comment: Some explanation would be helpful, along with your code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @chariothy is close but doesn't actually work. I just had a need to combine multiple tif files into a single pdf file and this is my solution, tested and working.

```
$pdf = new \Imagick();

foreach ($tif_file_paths as $file_path){

    $pdf->addImage(new \Imagick($file_path));
}

$pdf->writeImages('path/to/save/file/test-combined.pdf', true);
```